# Why are we getting "tls handshake error using curl"?

Tags: ssl, curl, wget

I'm trying to use curl to access a URL of an app we've developed internally, and on the server I'm seeing

`http: TLS handshake error from 1.2.3.4 remote error: tls: unknown certificate authority.`

This only happens when we hit the endpoint using curl (inside git bash ) or wget. When we use IE on Windows it works just fine. I've even tried re-installing git bash using Native SSL library (which should be the same as IE), but still getting the same error message.

Have even tried downloading the curl-ca-bundle.crt file and saving to the same place as the curl binary, or even directly telling it to use this file with curl --cacert option, but still no joy.

I've compared the root certs that IE is reporting, and the ones in that curl-ca-bundle.crt and they look the same (they don't line up exactly the same, but they have the same text in them between the BEGIN and END markers, one is just wider on the screen and therefore uses fewer lines if that makes sense).

Hopefully someone has ideas what to try next as two of us have been tearing our hair out all afternoon with this.

wget also gives an error message :-

`$ wget https://bler.com/admin/user
--2018-09-03 15:53:43--  https://bler.com/admin/user
Connecting to 132.146.1.142:8090... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify oss.dns.networks.bt.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to oss.dns.networks.bt.com insecurely, use '--no-check-certificate'.`

We're using a local proxy server, and HTTP_PROXY is set. It must be using the proxy, as we can see we're hitting the end point.

Comment: Is your server returning the full certificate chain? https://whatsmychaincert.com

Comment: I think you're reading the error message at the server as saying that the server is detecting a certificate error - however I suspect "remote error" means "the error message at the remote client" - so the problem is that curl and wget don't think your proxy/server's certificate is from a valid CA. Are you using the --proxy/----proxytunnel option to curl? What commandline are you using with curl? I think similarly with wget you will have to use some options to specify the proxy and make sure it will tunnel the ssl content.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use whatsmychaincert.com as the site is locked down to only our internal IPs and a few partners.

Comment: No I'm not using the --proxy option of curl, but I'm using https_proxy environment variable instead which has the same effect. If I unset this variable I just get a timeout instead.

Comment: Here's the full command line `curl -i -w "\n" -H "Accept: application/json; version=1.0" -u "admin:password" --digest -X GET https://oss.dns.networks.bt.com/admin/user`

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error. This problem occurs when you install on Golang web server the only certificate. You must use a certificate chain instead.

For example, Letsencrypt gives "cert.pem" and "fullchain.pem". "cert.pem" works in browsers, but curl cannot work with this file (curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate). "fullchain.pem" works fine in browsers and curl.